# Combine Counting Sort for multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, sorting, counting

I've been asked to create an algorithm which takes M arrays, all in range 1-k, where their sizes combined is 'n', and sort them all in O(k+n) together (same as counting sort). A naive counting sort will take O(km+n).

The obvious barrel to overcome is moving accross the auxiliary array m times. I offered the following solution but he said my complexity is O(km+n):
We will create vector_i for each array which states its own set of numbers. For instance, the array "1,5,4,1,2" will be represented as <2,1,0,1,1>.
Then, for every number, "attach" the values to create k numbers in the length of m. Now when we move past every cell in our counting array, we will instantly put the right amount of "i" valued numbers to the right arrays. (There will be pointers to our current position in each array).

He might misunderstood me, but it looks like a very clear O(k+n) to me. One answer that he endorsed combined all arrays imto one and put a marker on every element which states what array it belongs to.

I'm very confident with my soultion but I would love to hear reviews to make sure I'm not mistaken.
Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> We will create vector_i for each array which states its own set of numbers.

Since you need to see every one of the n elements to populate these vectors, this first part will take `O(n)` time.

> Now when we move past every cell in our counting array, we will instantly put the right amount of "i" valued numbers to the right arrays.

You create a vector for each of the m arrays, so there are m vectors. You also stated that each vector is `in range 1-k`. This means that there are a maximum total of `k*m` items in your newly created arrays. Since you go through these vectors one element at a time to populate the original arrays, the time complexity for this part is `O(km)`.

This brings the total time complexity to `O(km + n)`.

Comment: Hey Bimde, thank you for your answer. I understand that going through one vector at a time and looking in every cell will conclude in O(k*m) running time, but imagine you go through the array it self and then as you go through the "i" valued you skim through the vector i and then put every i to its place. it is very similar to the answer he endorsed, the only difference is that you don't get the exact same i's you get in the method I suggested.